# Agora SDK for fire stick application

Tags: android, android-tv, agora.io, amazon-fire-tv

I want to integrate Agora SDK for my fire stick application to share video.

Wanted to check feasibility of agora sdk for fire stick.

Would appreciate for any response. Also if any sample for Android TV/Fire stick can be provided for agora integration, it would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

Agora supports Android build targets, but a few things to keep in mind.

- The Firestick device doesn't have any built-in mic or camera so you will be limited to an audience view.
- FireOS may have modified the default audio/video codec support so this would be something to consider.

For the easiest integration on Android I would recommend taking a look at the Agora Android UIKit, its an open sourcce low-code solution for implementing Agora's Video SDK without having to spend the time building the UI and basic SDK implementation from scratch.

- [Agora Android UIKit QuickStart Guide](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/creating-an-android-video-streaming-application-with-three-lines-of-code/)
- [Agora Android UIKit GitHub Repo](https://github.com/agoraio-community/Android-UIKit)